# Unexpected behaviour for $this->authorize() in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Calling `$this->authorize('some.permission')` in a controller constructor always causes 403 error.
However `$this->middleware('can:some.permission')` works as expected. Why?

This is how the `some.permission` defined in the `AuthServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

     Gate::before(function (User $user) {
        if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return true; // This is ignored
        }
    });

     Gate::define('some.permission', function (User $user) {
        // return true; // This didn't work as well
        return $user->hasPermission('some.permission');
     });

}
```

Funny, but `Gate::before()` is ignored by `$this->authorize()`, which logically imho incorrect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when the controller is being instantiated, you do not have access to all features yet. You might want to look into: (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10334) which basically describes this issue(and has some answer to it, at the end).

Comment: I can remember also tried updating a config setting(language id) in a controllers constructor, which back then also did not work( not sure about now)

Comment: Thanks so much, seems authorize() only allowed in controller callbacks. Just tried and it worked